# Swift closures: Is it possible to specify the return type, without giving up implicit parameters?

Tags: swift, closures

Say you have this code:

```
let fib = sequence(state: (0, 1), next: { (state) -> Int in
    state = (state.1, state.0 + state.1)
    return state.0
})
```

Is it possible to annotate the type of the closure (as necessary for multi-expression closures such as this one), while still being able to use implicit closure parameters? Something like:

```
let fib = sequence(state: (0, 1), next: { (_:) -> Int in
    $0 = ($0.1, $0.0 + $0.1)
    return $0.0
})
```

Comment: Isn't enough to annotate `fib`? e.g. `let fib: Int`? Or explicitly put `as Int` after  `return`?

Comment: @Sulthan Nope, it's not

Comment: How about compacting it down into an unintelligible mess of a single statement `sequence(state: (0, 1), next: { ($0 = ($0.1, $0.0 + $0.1), $0.0).1 })`? :P (currently crashes the compiler, and frankly, I don't blame it)

Comment: @Hamish dont hurt the poor compiler :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into [Swift Grammar](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/closure-expression), specifically the syntax for *closure-expression*, we can see that *closure-parameter-clause* is the only required part of *closure-signature*.

Therefore the answer is no. If you want to specify *function-result* you have to also specify the parameters.

As a workaround, you can specify the result type by inferring, e.g. :

```
let fib: Int = ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried wrangling with the grammar but I couldn't find a production that would allow it. Thanks for double checking.

Comment: And the actual type here would be `UnfoldSequence<(Int, Int), Int>`. It's pretty long, which was why I was looking for an alternative

Comment: @Alexander  Oh, I don't use `sequence` much so I didn't realize. Wouldn't it be enough to put `return state.0 as Int` to infer the return value?